# Huge CPU cycles consumption due to an init service script

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, debian, beagleboneblack, systemd

I am currently working on Beaglebone Black (pre-installed Debian Linux Wheezy, kernel 3.8.13). I have written a simple service file which supposedly executes a pre-built binary "**main.bin**" file of a client program whenever the board boots up. The service file can be located as /etc/systemd/system/start_application.service

Service file contains these lines

```
[Unit]
Description=Client_Service
After=syslog.target network.target
[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/home/debian/Desktop/start_application
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

If I start the service and try to check the CPU usage (I have systemd installed and perfectly working)

```
root@beaglebone:~# systemctl start start_application.service
root@beaglebone:~# top
```

I tried multiple times, observed for hours to confirm and found that, the program started (Please see the main.bin) using systemctl consumes huge CPU%. [Here is the screenshot of the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wLC9l.png)

Instead of using the system service facility, if I execute the same program manually from command-line

```
root@beaglebone:~# cd /home/debian/Desktop/
root@beaglebone:/home/debian/Desktop# ./start_application
```

I found that it runs normally and consumes normal amount of CPU cycles. [Here is the screenshot of the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cp744.png).

Where am I making the mistake in the system service script ?

Comment: This site is for programming questions. We're not general software/hardware tech support.

Comment: Isn't it a question related to programming, linux, debian, systemd, CPU usage, script ? It's a very specific software related problem. may be I should edit the question a little bit.

Comment: I see no code, only system config stuff, so it's not programming, it's sysadmin stuff.

Comment: I have developed the code already and need to run it automatically now. Pretty much coding itself. Can you please help ?

Comment: add few code snippet of start_application, I think it's an issue of you code, not systemd as systemd only starts application and keep its status.

Comment: What is the situation of `./start_application &`?

Comment: _start_application contains following_
#! /bin/sh
#
# start_application
#
echo "Starting application"

/home/debian/Desktop/app/main.bin 127.0.0.1 2540 127.0.0.1 2541 127.0.0.1 2525 127.0.0.1 2345 samplelogfile
echo Done

Comment: ./start_application &                         _returns following_
[1] 16015

Comment: with _./start_application &_ the application is running in background with 1.7% CPU usage, pretty normal

Comment: Since, I found that the scripts in /etc/init.d are getting executed (its a sysvinit way of system initialization) I wrote a script by modifying the skeleton file available in /etc/init.d. Added the script to defaults. But it never executes. Why is it not getting executed ?

Comment: Don't use sysvinit scripts, please. The fact they are still remaining in Jessie is bad enough itself.
Note, that you are running your app from it's directory manually.
Try to add
`WorkingDirectory=/home/debian/Desktop/` before the ExecStart.

Comment: @Hardy Rust - I have added the path correctly. Dev guys who worked on systemd helped for solving the problem on a chat. actually my app has an infinite call to the poll() function. when I manually execute the script, app gets the tty as stdin, but when I  do it using systemd, app gets /dev/null as stdin. so basically it broke with systemd, I had to fake the pipes to solve it.